# Creating Google Credentials object for Google Drive API without loading from file

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am trying to create a google credentials object to access google drive. I have the tokens and user data stored in a session thus I am trying to create the object without loading them from a credentials.json file. I am handling the authentication when a user first logs in the web app and storing the tokens inside the user session, the session has a time out of 24 hours same as the default access token thus after 24 hours the user is requested to log in again so a new session with a valid access token is created. So my idea is to reuse the access token to limit the amount of log ins and improve user experience.

This is a small piece of code on how I'm trying to create the google credentials object

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

access_token = request.session['access_token']
gCreds = GoogleCredentials( 
         access_token, 
         os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
         os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'), 
         refresh_token=None, 
         token_expiry=None,
         token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, 
         user_agent='Python client library',
         revoke_uri=None)
build('drive', 'v3', credentials = gCred)
```

Whenever I try to run this code I get the following error:

```
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]"

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for your GoogleCredentials method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object was build correctly, there was no issue with building the object this way

```
access_token = request.session['access_token']
gCreds = GoogleCredentials( 
         access_token, 
         os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
         os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'), 
         refresh_token=None, 
         token_expiry=None,
         token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, 
         user_agent='Python client library',
         revoke_uri=None)
build('drive', 'v3', credentials = gCred)
```

The problem was caused at an earlier stage, when registering the scopes

```
oauth = OAuth(config)
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url='',
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
    }
)
```

Comment: You understand that exactly what i said in the first part of my answer.

Comment: yes, I just thought that it's enough to only add the scopes in the app configuration in the google console, but it wasn't, I needed to register them using the auth.register()

Answer (score 3):

So what are scopes. Scopes define the access that you are requesting from the user.  In this case you want to access their Google drive account, but how much access do you need depends upon the methods you will be using.

If you are just using file.list then you could request a read only scope as your not going to be writing anything.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

Yet if your going to use file.create well your going to need a write scope.  You need permission to write to their google account

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

I cant see from your code how you are handling the authorization at all. So Lets start by looking at the official [google drive python sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)

In the code below notice how they call

```
InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
```

And define the scopes of access they would like to request.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## the error message

The error message

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]">
> successfully connected to drive

Actually means that you have requsted one scope from the user lets say read only yet you are trying to use it with a method that requires write access. So your request has insufficient authentication scopes.

Fix your code to request the proper scope delete the refresh token you have now and request authorization of the user again with the proper scope.

Comment: The reason why I am trying to create the gCreds object and not load it from a file is because I get all the data I need when the user initially logs into the web app and store the tokens and user data in a session (you can see how I request the access token from the session's storage request.session['access_token'], I do this to limit the times of log ins), is it possible to somehow create the creds object without loading data from token.json and credentials.json?

Comment: I edited the question description to provide more details

Comment: refresh token is loaded fr token.json

Comment: Why the bounty?  Does it not work?

Comment: No, I need to create the credentials object by reusing the access tokens I have stored in the session without loading it from a file, because otherwise I would have to authenticate the users twice.  So I am trying to avoid that, this example has always worked it's just that I need it slightly different and not sure why my approach doesn't work .

Comment: What about [credentials.py#L332](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/29db1397626e6c999144c34b466b2fe24b1b42fd/google/oauth2/credentials.py#L332)

Comment: Request had insufficient authentication scopes  <-- Is because what ever system you used to create that access token did not request the scope you need.  For example https ://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.  You can find that at the top of my answer already.

Comment: so if I was to use redentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(data, scopes) I would need to pass the authorised user data as the data? not the access token?

Comment: Wild guess is its just an object.  The same object built by loading the file.  I haven't tried it though.